# When creating a virtual machine with Ubuntu, how do you grab the SSH key from the keyvault through the interface?

Tags: azure, virtual-machine, azure-keyvault

I want to store the private key credentials in an azure keyvault. I crated the keyvault, and then generated the SSH private key that is stored in the keys blade of the keyvault. Now, I want to use the private key in my keyvault when creating the VM for the first time with Ubuntu. The problem is that through the portal, after selecting "Use existing key stored in Azure", it doesn't see any keys in my keyvault.

Basic question, how do I get the key with this method? Is it an access issue?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

okay,

the public key is an Azure resource that it's looking for.

the private key is the downloadable  file that needs to be stored in a keyvault.